# Appending custom classes to list in another class

Tags: python, list, class, object, append

I just typed the code below. I expected to see this output: "0.5 -- 1.5". But I am seeing this: "1.5 -- 1.5":

```
class ponto:
    x=0
    y=0
    z=0

class estado:
    pontos = []
    prox_bloco = 1

#Construir Estado Inicial
p = ponto()
p.x = 0.5
p.y = 0.5
p.z = 0.5
init = estado()
init.pontos.append(p)
p.x = 1.5
init.pontos.append(p)

p1 = init.pontos[0]
p2 = init.pontos[1]
print(p1.x,"--",p2.x)
```

Could anyone explain this and help me fix it?

Answer (score 1):

First: You should use instance variables instead of class variables:

```
class ponto:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.z = 0

class estado:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pontos = []
        self.prox_bloco = 1
```

Second: When you change `p.x` you will change it on the instance, you don't create an new instance that way!

Instead you should create a new instance (e.g. using [`copy.copy` or `copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html)) and then change it on the new instance:

```
import copy

p = ponto()
p.x = 0.5
p.y = 0.5
p.z = 0.5
init = estado()
init.pontos.append(p)
p = copy.copy(p)       # copy "p"
p.x = 1.5              # set the variable on the copy
init.pontos.append(p)  # append the copy

p1 = init.pontos[0]
p2 = init.pontos[1]
print(p1.x,"--",p2.x)
```

This gives the expected result:

```
0.5 -- 1.5
```